# Customizing list of listing

Tags: listings

I need to customize my list of listings page by adding a period after each caption (e.g. `Listing 1.1.`). I couldn't find the correct place to insert the period in the code.

[image]

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{TEST}
\author{AYILDIZ}
\date{October 2020}

\usepackage{listings}


\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup
  \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
  \def\l@lstlisting##1##2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}{Listing ##1}{##2}}
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lol}}%
  \clearpage %<---------------
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}%
  \tableofcontents \egroup}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\lstlistoflistings

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}\label{chp:Introduction}

Interest in exploring the genetic data of organisms is growing everyday.

Miusov, as a man man of breeding and deilcacy, could not but feel some inwrd qualms, when he reached the Father Superior's with Ivan: he felt ashamed of havin lost his temper. He felt that he ought to have disdaimed that despicable wretch, Fyodor Pavlovitch, too much to have been upset by him in Father Zossima's cell, and so to have forgotten himself. "Teh monks were not to blame, in any case," he reflceted, on the steps. "And if they're decent people here (and the Father Superior, I understand, is a nobleman) why not be friendly and courteous withthem? I won't argue, I'll fall in with everything, I'll win them by politness, and show them that I've nothing to do with that Aesop, thta buffoon, that Pierrot, and have merely been takken in over this affair, just as they have."

He determined to drop his litigation with the monastry, and relinguish his claims to the wood-cuting and fishery rihgts at once. He was the more ready to do this becuase the rights had becom much less valuable, and he had indeed the vaguest idea where the wood and river in quedtion were.

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={My Code},language=C]
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return(0);
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the definition of `\numberline`:

```latex
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\renewcommand\lstlistoflistings{\bgroup
  \let\contentsname\lstlistlistingname
  \def\numberline##1{\hb@xt@\@tempdima{##1.\hfil}}% <--- added by egreg
  \def\l@lstlisting##1##2{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{2.3em}{Listing ##1}{##2}}%
  \let\lst@temp\@starttoc \def\@starttoc##1{\lst@temp{lol}}%
  \cleardoublepage %<---------------
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Listings}%
  \tableofcontents \egroup}%
}
\makeatother
```

[image]

Also you should use `\cleardoublepage` and not `\clearpage`. If you change your mind and start using two-side printing, the simple `\clearpage` would be wrong. With one-sided printing, the two commands are equivalent.